# Why weights dont change K-mean cluster center position in sci-kit learn package?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to calculate center position of a cluster with weights option. But weights seems not to work.

Here is the simple script which represent the problem

```
X = []
weights = []
for x in range(-10,10):
    for y in range(-10,10):
        X+= [[x,y]]
        if x>0 and y>0:
            weights += [10000]
        else:
            weights += [1]

X = np.array(X)
weights = np.array(weights)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(X,weights)
print kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

It prints `[[-0.5 -0.5]]` with weights *10000* in the 1st quarter.

I expect it to be approx `(5,5)`

EDIT1:
Trying to call fit() as:

```
fit(X,sample_weight=weights)
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
```

Adding second variable, does not help either:

```
fit(X,None,weights)
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: fit() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the way you call the `fit` method.
You need to pass the `weights` as a keyword argument

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(X, sample_weight=weights)
```

**Explanation**:

The signature of the `fit` method is the following:

```
KMeans.fit(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None)
```

By calling `KMeans.fit(self, X, weights)` then implicitly `y = weights`. And since `y` is ignored there is no effect.

See [official docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have tried this in the first place, but i got the error:
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
Does it work for you?

Comment: I think you need to get a more recent version of scikit-learn

Comment: Changing version from 0.19.2 to 0.20.2 solved the problem. Thank you!